# Capture text from popup using Protractor selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I would like to capture text from popup using protractor using getText but I'm unable to do that. Below is snippet of HTML [HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWffv.png)
This popup stays for a while(around few seconds) and disappears. Can someone please help me to capture the text from popup.

this.getTestMessage = function () {

```
    var maxAgentCredit1 = element(by.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/ng-view/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a"));
    var button = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='ngdialog1']/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/button[2]"));
    maxAgentCredit1.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    button.click();
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(popUpRep), 3000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
    element(by.css("p.ng-binding.ng-scope.notice.type-NOTICE.ng-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active")).getText().then(function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you get a timeout? If so, it could be that the classes in the popup are not all there, have you tried this also `element(by.css('.notifications [ng-repeat="item in notices"]'))`

Comment: @wswebcreation: Thanks for the response. I don't get timeout issue, but not sure whether **wait** is doing its job either. All I get is 'Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .notifications [ng-repeat="item in notices"])', But I am able to find the pop up manually using your css selector(using firebug)

Comment: @wswebcreation Please let me know if you need more details. Below is the stack:Stack:
     'NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .notifications [ng-repeat="item in notices"])
        at WebDriverError (C:\Users\kiran.shigli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
        at NoSuchElementError (C:\Users\kiran.shigli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:168:5)
        at elementArrayFinder.getWebElements.then'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@wswebcreation** I was able to capture the text from the notification pop up using protractor's **ExpectedConditions** using your css selector. Thanks for the help.

```
{this.getPopUpMessage = function () {
    browser.wait(until.stalenessOf(notification), 5000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(notification), 5000);
    return notification.getText();
    }}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm thankyou...but without stalenessOf also worked fine..can you please explain the significance of stalenessOf in the toaster? @Kiran

Comment: also return didnt worked for me;;so i have used expect(toaster.getText()).toContain(""); should i turn off the ignoresynchronization again?